# Запуск Minecraft с кастомным путем из самописного лаунчера на C# с помощью Windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, minecraft, launcher

Пробовал написать, но ничего не получилось.

```
ProcessStartInfo mcStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
    "C:\\.Severaldimensions\\JAVA\\bin\\java.exe",
    "-Xmx" + RAMChoose.AvailableRAM + "m \n-cp " + pathtomc + "C:\\.Severaldimensions\\TechnoMagic\\libraries\\net\\java\\jinput\\jinput\\2.0.5\\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\\.Severaldimensions\\TechnoMagic\\libraries\\org\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\lwjgl_util\\2.9.1\\lwjgl_util-2.9.1.jar" + "-Djava.library.path = C:\\.Severaldimensions\\TechnoMagic/versions\\1.12.2-forge-14.23.5.2855\\natives net.minecraft.client.Minecraft" + "--username" + textBox1.Text + " --version 1.12.2" + " --gameDir" + gamedir + " --assetsDir" + gamedir + "/assets" + " --assetIndex 1.12.2" + " --uuid 1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0g" + " --accessToken 1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0g" + " --userProperties {twitch_access_token:[1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0g]}" + " --userType legacy");
Process.Start(mcStartInfo);
```

[image: Имеем такой путь к папке natives и 1.12.2-forge-14.23.5.2855.jar]

[image: И такой путь к java]

[image: Имеем вот такой набор библиотек]

Comment: `но ничего не получилось.` вот после этих слов вот прямо сразу стало всё понятно.

Comment: Проверьте, все ли пробелы на своих местах, мне кажется как минимум парочки не хватает. Но вы же попробовали получившуюся строку вывести на экран? Что там получилось? Ну и судя по всему у вас проект .NET Framework 4.x, верно? Иначе где-то потерялся UseShellExecute.

Comment: нет, проект построен на .net core и подскажите пожалуйста что за UseShellExecute, подскажите, требуется ли именно .net framework?

Comment: Не знаю, требуется ли оно вам. А вообще это параметр у ProcessStartInfo. Документация же есть.